# Create Microsoft Outlook calendar entries from another system (oracle db)

Tags: oracle, outlook, calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I was wondering if someone knows a solution to create a calendar entry from another system into someone his outlook calender.
The requirments are that the calendar entry is created automatically, and that's it's accepted. (no interaction from the user needed).
I found a simple solution where you send a .ics file to the user, but he has to open the mail, double click the ics file, and accept it.
That's what I don't want!

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Leander

Comment: This may help you, it has the ability to create calendar items: http://ora-00001.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/ms-exchange-api-for-plsql.html e.g. `ms_ews_util_pkg.create_calendar_item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Calendar Entry using one of the Mailbox API eg either EWS or MAPI if you can export the item as ICS file there there is a sample of how to import and Item from and ICS using EWS in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672319(v=exchg.150).aspx